# How do make a div scrollLeft based on clientX mousemove

Tags: javascript

I have a scrollable div that I want to scroll when dragging the mouse inside of it.

I have a very basic implementation in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/riha/pen/powRKdX).

I can't however understand how to think of `scrollLeft` and `clientX`? I think I need ‍ to set the `scrollLeft` position to the `clientX + the position of the scrollBar once the drag staretd`. But they are somehow on different relative positions?

Resulting in a bit of "jumpy" feeling when starting to drag.

```
function mouseMove(event) {
  if (!dragging) return;
  
  const {scrollLeft} = initScroll;
  
  // Even if I click exactly where the bar starts the positions are way off ...
  div.scrollLeft = event.clientX + scrollLeft;
}
```

In this image I've just clicked at the start of the bar but the scrollLeft is at 548 and the clientX is at 282?

How can I make this a bit smoother?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the `initPosition` every time the mouse moves and is dragging, and instead of reassigning the `scrollLeft`, you can subtract from it the difference between the `clientX` and the `initPosition`:

```js
var dragging = false;
var startX = 0;
var elem = document.querySelector('.draggable');
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => (dragging = true,startX = e.clientX))
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => (dragging = false))
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!dragging) return;
  elem.scrollLeft -= e.clientX - startX;
  startX = e.clientX;
})
```

```css
.draggable {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.draggable .content {
  width: 200%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.